# Trigger covered xml object onclick event

Tags: android

DrawerLayout is overlaying gridView so onCLick event setted on gridView children is not being triggered. If I put gridView above drawerLayout, when a click the hamburger, navigationView is overlayed by GRidView...

Any suggestion?

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:columnCount="3"
        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_layout"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Ty in advance.

Comment: give fix height of gridLayout or "wrap content"

Comment: Does not works, but ty anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution... DrawerLayout always has to be root, the first xlm tag in file.

Answer (score 0):

just add a code to the NavigationView

```
clickable="true"
```

like this fix your code

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```